# Send weekly email with breakdown of hard disk space used/free

Tags: linux, debian, cron

I would like a bash script that sends me a weekly email displaying the breakdown of disk space used based on a array of file list. Would this be possible using the `df -h`

Had a look on Google to find anything that I could use without much luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use cron to run a job and send the results to you.

Something like:

```
0 1 * * 6 /bin/df -h | mail -s "Disk usage" john.magnolia@example.com
```

in your crontab will run once a week on Saturday at 1AM.

This assumes that your server is set up to send mail to your email address.

If you need something more complicated, you can wrap the command in a script that does stuff.

Comment: Thanks this pointed me in the right direction of: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/shell-script-to-watch-the-disk-space.html

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand the "array of file list part", but it's certainly possible with `df` and `cron`:

For a very basic version, add the following script to your `/etc/cron.weekly` directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
df -h | mailx youraddress@example.com -s "Weekly storage report"
```

This requires that you have mailx and a working SMTP system installed.